# SQL Filtrar por mayor

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Hola buenos dias tengo una tabla de transacciones con las columnas: "LEGAJO" y "FECHA" (int)
Un legajo puede tener mas de una transaccion, por ende, el legajo se repite a lo largo de la tabla.
Necesito construir una query la cual me permita traer la ultima transaccion de cada legajo.

¿Es posible quedarme para cada legajo el registro con fecha (entero) mas alto?

```
Output actual

Select * from transacciones
LEGAJO | FECHA
_______________
1    | 01012022
2    | 02012022
3    | 02012022
1    | 03012022
3    | 03012022

Output deseado:
LEGAJO | FECHA
 _______________
  1    | 03012022
  2    | 02012022
  3    | 03012022
```

Comment: group by por lejago y max de fecha..

Comment: Hola Agustín podrías decir si la respuesta dada te resultó útil, gracias

Answer (score 1):

Para eso existen las **funciones de agregación**, en este caso específico la **función de agregación** que debes utilizar es **Max**. También debes hacer uso de la **cláusula group by**, la cual te permite agrupar la información por determinada columna o determinadas columnas, en tu caso agrupar por la **columna legajo**:

```
select legajo, Max(fecha)
from transacciones
group by legajo
```

Lo que haces aquí es **agrupar por la columna legajo**, y por cada grupo obtienes el registro donde la fecha sea la mayor(fecha más reciente).